# Why am I getting error -4700 (attempt to use new function mode) when running a query?

Tags: sql, db2, mainframe, db2-zos

I tried running the query in SPUFI as :

```
select * from (select * from emptable 
order by empno asc fetch first 10 rows only) as A 
order by empno desc fetch first 1 rows only;
```

The error returned is :

> sqlcode = -4700, error: attempt to use new function before new function mode.

I am running DB2 for z/OS version 9.

Comment: Hmm, according to the manual -4700 is "-4700
ATTEMPT TO USE NEW FUNCTION BEFORE NEW FUNCTION MODE". But I can't find anything special about your query that should require NFM on a current DB2-installation. What version of DB2 are you running (in CM)?

Comment: Hi Piet , I just ran the query -  select getvariable('SYSIBM.VERSION`) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 and the result was DSN09010 .. so i think its version 9

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using `order by` and `fetch first` in a subselect - which is a feature that has not existed before version 9 of DB2 for z/OS:

> In prior versions of DB2 for z/OS, the ORDER BY and FETCH FIRST
>   n
>   ROWS
>   ONLY clauses were supported only at the statement level as part of
>   select-statement or a SELECT INTO statement. Version 9 delivers additional
>   flexibility by allowing both FETCH FIRST
>   n
>   ROWS ONLY and ORDER BY clauses
>   when they are specified as part of a subselect or a fullselect statement.

(DB2 Version 9.1 for z/OS - What's New? GC18-9856-12)

Obviously your DB2-installation is still running in compatibility mode and has not been switched to new-function mode, so this feature is not yet available.

Please note that your installation has a more severe problem than  CM <-> NFM since

> Support for DB2 for z/OS Version 9 was discontinued on June 27, 2014.